# unsigned char, why output is 254 expected is 255

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h> // header file
int main()
{
unsigned char a=255;
unsigned char b=0;
unsigned char c;
c=a++ + --b; // a++ is 0 and --b is 255;
printf("result=%d\n",c);
return 0;
}
```

output :
result=254

confuse why output is not 255,how 254 ?.

Please let me know if i missed anything ?

Comment: put the assignment to c on seperate lines of code and see where it went wrong.  I assume the a++ is not happening when you think it is (it happens AFTER execution), and you end up with 255 + 255 = 254

Comment: how 255 + 255= 254 ?

Comment: See @ODYN-Kons answer below but ill repost it here for you:

255 + 255 = 255 + (1 + 254) = (255 + 1) + 254 = 0 + 254 = 254

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a++` is a postfix operator, meaning it will be evaluated **after** `a` is used.  If you try `++a`, you'll get what you expect.

If you break down `c=a++ + --b;` you effectively get this:

```
b = b - 1;
c = a + b;
a = a + 1;
```

Comment: okay then a++ + --b (255 + 255) output will be different. why 254

Comment: 255 + 255 = 255 + (1 + 254) = (255 + 1) + 254 = 0 + 254 = 254

Comment: can you please elaborate above statements

Comment: When you added 255 and 255 as unsigned chars, the result is 254.  The statements above just show how you can reason about it.

Comment: since unsiged char is 8 bits, 256 = 0, meaning the unsigned char will wrap around.  I believe thats the concept your missing, does this help?  If you open windows calculator, and go to programming mode (alt+3), enter 256 and see the bit pattern has the 9th bit set, and all lower 8 bits zeroed out.  Since unsinged char is only 8 bits, this effectively sets the unsigned char to 0, hence the "wrap around" back to 0.

Comment: why 255 + (1 + 254) ?

Comment: He's showing that you overflow `unsigned char` once, and you have 254 left

Comment: @PankajSuryavanshi In C unsigned types "wrap around". If the number can not be represented by an unsigned type it is calculated modulo TYPE_MAX+1. In this case: `255+255` is `510` and `510 mod 256` is `254`.